# On correct use of Limit for multivariable function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

V 12.1 on windows.

This limit  $\lim_{(x \rightarrow 0,y\rightarrow 0)} \frac{x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2}$ depends on the direction. So the limit does not exist, or could be written as Maple does it, which is $-1\dots1$, here is the help from Maple on this:

[image]

How can one get Mathematica to give this result? Now Mathematica says the limit is $1$. I tried the `Direction` option but not able to make it change its mind.

```
f = (x^2 - y^2)/(x^2 + y^2);
Limit[f, {x -> 0, y -> 0}]
(* 1 *)
```

But we see the limit depends on the direction

```
 Limit[Limit[f, x -> 0], y -> 0]
 (* -1 *)

 Limit[Limit[f, y -> 0], x -> 0]
 (*  1 *)
```

Here is also Maple to confirm

```
restart;
f:=(x^2-y^2)/(x^2+y^2);
limit(f, [x=0,y=0]);
```

[image]

Btw, this is not the only one I found, here is another

```
f = (x^2*y^2)/(x^4 + y^4);
Limit[f, {x -> 0, y -> 0}]
(* 0 *)
```

Maple gives

```
restart;
f:=x^2*y^2/(x^4+y^4);
limit(f,[y=0,x=0])
  (* 0 .. 1/2 *)
```

And another one (this one is from [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PtWa4gkGzlM) actually, so you can see they also say there the limit does not exist)

```
f = (x^4 - 4 y^2)/(x^2 + 2 y^2);
Limit[f, {x -> 0, y -> 0}]
(* 0 *)

restart;
f:=(x^4-4*y^2)/(x^2+2*y^2);
limit(f, [x=0,y=0]);
(* -2 .. 0 *)
```

So I have feeling I am not using Limit in Mathematica correctly, or missing something about its correct use, but do not now know how to correct it. As I said, I tried different `Direction` option.

Comment: The quote from https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=limit/return&term=limit/return  "If limit returns a numeric range it means that the value of the limiting expression is known to lie in that range for arguments restricted to some neighborhood of the limit point.  It does not necessarily imply that the limiting expression is known to achieve every value infinitely often in this range"

Comment: This is very clearly documented in the usage messages on the reference page for `Limit` (hence the vote to close).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You compute multivariate limits with:

```
Limit[f, {x, y} -> {0, 0}]
```

> Indeterminate

I don't know if it's possible to get a range of possibilities like Maple does.

Comment: (1) `Limit` will generate `Interval` objects under some circumstances;  try `Limit[Sin[x] + Sin[x^2], x -> Infinity]`. I'm not sure why it doesn't do so here (or, indeed, when you remove one of the sine functions from the above snippet.  (2) The functions `MaxLimit` and `MinLimit` will calculate the upper and lower ends of the interval if the function indeed approaches an interval.

Answer (score 7):

A general way to deal with multivariate limits is to introduce a parametrization of the path by which the limiting point is being approached.

```
f = (x^2 - y^2)/(x^2 + y^2);
Limit[f/.{y->r Sin[θ],x->r Cos[θ]},r->0]
Out[1]= Cos[2 θ]
```

From this calculation, it becomes evident that depending on the direction the limit can be any real number in the range from -1 to 1.

Answer (score 5):

The lower and upper limits of the function under consideration (see [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_superior_and_limit_inferior) for info) can be found by the following commands of Mathematica

```
MinLimit[(x^2 - y^2)/(x^2 + y^2), {x, y} -> {0, 0}]
(*-1*)
MaxLimit[(x^2 - y^2)/(x^2 + y^2), {x, y} -> {0, 0}]
(*1*)
```

These commands are stronger than the `limit` command of Maple. Here is an example:

```
MaxLimit[Sin[x/y], {x, y} -> {0, 0}]
(*1*)
```

, but

```
limit(sin(x/y), [x = 0, y = 0]);
```

returns the input.